# Laravel: Get users based on Eloquent relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `User` model which has an attribute `type` among other attributes. Type is used to identify *parents* and *children*.

Parent and children (students) have *many-to-many* relationship.
Also students belong to one or many *groups* (model `Group`).

User model

```
/**
 * Filter the scope of users to student type.
 *
 * @param $query
 */
public function scopeStudent($query){
    $query->where('type', '=', 'std');
}

/**
 * Filter the scope of users to parent type.
 *
 * @param $query
 */
public function scopeParent($query){
    $query->where('type', '=', 'prt');
}

/**
 * List of groups the user is associated with.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function groups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group', 'group_user_assoc')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

/**
 * List of students associated with the user(parent).
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function children(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'student_parent_assoc', 'parent_id', 'student_id')
                ->withPivot('relation');
}

/**
 * List of parents associated with the user(student).
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function parents(){
    return $this->BelongsToMany('\App\User', 'student_parent_assoc', 'student_id', 'parent_id')
                ->withPivot('relation');
}
```

The aforementioned relations are working correctly.

Below are my association tables.

```
student_parent_assoc
----------------------
+------------+------------------+------+-----+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+
| student_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| parent_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| relation   | varchar(25)      | YES  |     |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+

group_user_assoc
----------------------
+------------+------------------+------+-----+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+
| group_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+
```

I need to find students who do not belong to any group along with their parents. I have managed to find students like so

```
$students = User::student()
                ->whereDoesntHave('groups')
                ->get();
```

**Question:**
Now I want to find parents of these students. But I am not able to build an eloquent query for the same. How do I do it?

Note: I could get collection of students from above query and run a `foreach` loop to get their parents like so

```
$parents = new Collection;
foreach($students as $student) {
    foreach($student->parents as $parent) {
        $parents->push($parent);
    }
}
$parents = $parents->unique();
```

But I need a `Builder` object and not a `Collection` as I am using [Datatables server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) with [Yajra/datatables](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle).

Comment: use User::student()->with('parents'). This is eager loading of relations https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: But that won't give me parents directly. They will be inside nested relationship. I'd prefer getting a `Builder` object for parents.

Comment: ok - then you can load your students and after that call $students->load(['parents' -> function($query) { //modify your builder as needed }])

Comment: in generally you can do the same in with() function where the loaded relation Query Builder can also be modified with a callback function

Comment: Could you please explain how? I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve it like so

```
$students = User::student()
                ->with('parents')
                ->whereDoesntHave('groups')
                ->has('parents') //to get only those students having parents
                ->get();

$parent_ids = array();

// get ids of all parents
foreach ($students as $student) {
    foreach ($student->parents as $parent) {
        $parent_ids[] = $parent->user_id;
    }
}

// build the query
$users = User::parent()
             ->with('children')
             ->whereIn('user_id', $parent_ids);
```

I would still like it if someone could suggest a better and simple approach.

Answer (score 2):

for loading `parents` relation you hae to use eager loading.
2 methods are `with($relation)` and `load($relation)`.  Difference is just you get parents already with result objects or load them later.

So in your example to get parents you can use with('parents') or if you want to modify resulted set:

```
User::student()
->with(['parents' => function ($parentsQueryBuilder) {
    $parentsQueryBuilder->where('condition', 1)->whereIn('condition2', [1,2,3]);
}])
->whereDoesntHave('groups')
->get();
```

Then you will get your parents in a relationship aswell but performance will be high cause you will spend only one query to load parents to your objects. Then you can pluck if needed them in one collection like this:

```
$students->pluck('parents')->flatten()->unique();
```

Or example 2 - if you just need all parents related to selected students - almost the same what eager loading does:

```
$studentIds = $students->modeKeys();
User::parent()->whereHas('children', function ($query) use($studentIds) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $studentIds);
})->get();
```

**UPDATED**

For getting builder of parents try this:

```
/** BelongsToMany   <- relation query builder */    
$relation = with(new User)->query()->getRelation('parents');

$relation->addEagerConstraints($students->all());
```

This will create for you new instance of BelongsToMany relation and attach Constraints of whereIn($studentIds) to it. Then hitting `->get()` on it you have to receive related $parents

Comment: I still don't understand how I'll get a `Builder` object for parents.

Comment: you need `Builder` object for what? According to your example you want "Handling this at query level would be much faster." - I've provided you a method to load parents with one query

Comment: Sorry for that. I am using datatables server side processing. I have updated my question.

Comment: Btw, your solution doesn't work. I get this query for "example 2": `select * from `user_master` where `user_master`.`deleted_at` is null and `type` = ? and (select count(*) from `student_parent_assoc` as `self_512c9c60fe3b23ff75ab3b88cf3c9fc8` where `self_512c9c60fe3b23ff75ab3b88cf3c9fc8`.`parent_id` = `user_master`.`user_id` and `user_id` in (?, ?, ...) and `user_master`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1`. This gives blank results as the `user_id in` part gets students' user ids.

Comment: What is `$students` in `$relation->addEagerConstraints($students->all());`? Is it an instance of `Model` or `Collection`?

Comment: It is collection of your students